# Create a record to the database without a form in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, object, record

In my controller I have defined a method that I want to save to my database automatically without a form.

This is what I have so far, but nothing is being saved to the database.

**Here's the method**

```
def recommended_recipes
    @today = Date.today

    @recRecipe = RecommendedRecipe.where(user_id: current_user, day: @today)

    if @recRecipe.blank?
        response = RestClient.get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/mealplans/generate?targetCalories=3000&timeFrame=day", headers={"X-Mashape-Key" => "",
            "Accept" => "application/json"})

        @parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response)
        @recRecipes = @parsedResponse['meals']

        @recRecipesNutrients = @parsedResponse['nutrients']
        @totalCalories = @recRecipesNutrients['calories']
        @totalProteins = @recRecipesNutrients['protein']
        @totalFat = @recRecipesNutrients['fat']
        @totalCarbohydrates = @recRecipesNutrients['carbohydrates']

        @newRecRecipe = RecommendedRecipe.create(meals_response: @recRecipes, total_calories: @totalCalories, total_proteins: @totalProteins, total_fat: @totalFat, total_carbohydrates: @totalCarbohydrates, day: @today, user_id: current_user)
    end
end
```

I want to save the **@newRecipe** to my database called **recommended_recipes** whenever the method is called.
How can I make a record in the database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I achieve my goal. Currently it's not saving anything. I'll update my question.

Comment: Begin by changing `RecommendedRecipe.create` to `RecommendedRecipe.create!`. If no error is thrown, then chances are `@recRecipe.blank?` is evaluating to `false`. You might try changing `if @recRecipe.blank?` to `unless @recRecipe.any?`. If an error *is* thrown, then chances are you have a problem with your validations.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of kicking myself in the head I did this in the model:

```
class RecommendedRecipe < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

I added the **optional: true**